# Flash in Python

Tags: python, air, rich-internet-application

I was exploring possibilities of [Rich Internet applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application) using Python. The most awesome possibility I found was of programming in [IronPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython) and running it as a [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight). Is there something similar available for [Adobe AIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime)? I.e. programing in Python and run in Adobe AIR (Flash, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [libming](http://www.libming.org/) to generate Macromedia Flash files, it has Python bindings too, you can see some Python examples at "[Python, Ming and Flash](http://code.rancidbacon.com/PythonMingAndFlash)".

Another library is "[SSWF -- A complete library to generate Flash animations](http://sswf.sourceforge.net/libsswf/)", which is in C, so can be easily used from Python if needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of resources out there for Flex/AIR integration with Python, just google the two of them together. A good one is "[Python Resources for Flex Development](http://blog.jodybrewster.net/2008/04/17/python-resources-for-flex-development/)".

Comment: I think OP doesn't want some integration tools but want to write python code which can run as flash

Comment: well,nothing. the question was out of curiosity rather than finding an alternative.